# Intellisense flickers when working with asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, intellisense

When writing c# code in a view, the intellisense pops up and disappears after a second.
For example I am trying to use the `Html.DropDownFor` function, the intellisense shows up when I start typing the 'Html' part, but quickly disappears before I can even select anything.

Is there anything I can do about it?
Edit: I noticed the intellisense is working when first starting visual studio, but then it starts flickering after I alt+tab into another program and return to visual studio in any way. The issue sticks permanently after.

Edit: This seems to have been fixed in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Are you using any extensions that mess with intellisense (ReSharper, DevExpress, etc)?  You can try starting visual studio in safe mode (devenv.exe /safemode) to disable all extensions.  If the problem happens with that switch then you know for sure that it isn't an extension causing the problem.

Comment: Safe mode did not fix the issue (also no addons installed), but I did notice that it works fine until i alt+tab into another program and then return. Adding it to OP.

Comment: Is it only Alt-Tab that messes it up, not just switching applications "normally" using the taskbar?

Comment: Strangely, yes, only alt+tab. I tried presing those keys in visual studio one by one(and in different combinations) to see if something would get 'unstuck', but nothing helps.

Comment: Is it possible you accidentally turned on "sticky keys" or some other access ability feature in Windows?

Comment: I was using MouseKeys. I turned it off and there was no change. Thanks for trying to help, though ! It isn't a critical bug, but it makes intellisense completely useless since you can't rely on it.

Comment: Well, I'm out of ideas.  I'll let you know if I think of anything else.